# How to determine the addressable memory capacity in bytes knowing the bits for the operand address?

Tags: memory-address

If I have say a 64-bit instruction, which has 2 bytes (16 bits) for opcode and the rest for operand address, I can determine that I have 48bits for the address (`64-16`). The maximum value that can be displayed with 48 bits plus 1 to account for address 0 is my go to number. This would be `2^48`. However, I have the problem with the understanding of this in terms of the iB units.

`2^48` is `2^40 (TiB) x 2^8 = 256TiB`. But since `TiB = 2^40` **BYTES**, when did the `2^48` become a **BYTE**? I generally believed that to get the number of bytes I'd have to divide by 8, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Could someone explain why this works?

Answer (score 0):

A [*byte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) is by definition the smallest chunk of memory which has an address. Whatever number of address bits, the resulting address is the address of a byte, by definition. In all (or at least, most) computer architectures existing today, a byte is the same as an [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)), that is, eight bits; but historically there were popular computer architectures with 6 bit bytes, or 12 bit bytes, or even other more exotic number of bits per byte.